# Jade not reading number element from JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, express

I currently have a database(Mongoose) whose schema is defined as:

```
var CommentTableSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    name: String,
    body: String,
    parentCommentID: String,
    depth: Number, // the depth of the comment to which it is nested.
});
CommentTableSchema.set('collection', 'comment');
```

I save a new comment in my database by doing:

```
var comment = mongoose.model('comment', CommentTableSchema);
        var currentComment = new comment({name: request.body.name, body: request.body.comment, parentCommentID: "" , depth: 1});
        currentComment.save(function (err, currentComment) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("saving error : " + currentComment);
            }
            else {
                console.log("saved!");
            }
        });
```

I pass the results of `comment.find` to my home.jade file. In the jade file I have the following lines(commentsTable is the results of `comment.find`)

```
-each comment in commentsTable
    div
        -console.log("comment depth: " + comment.depth)
        if comment.hasOwnProperty('depth') 
            |has depth
        else
            |no depth
```

This outputs "no depth" on my browser page. However the line `-console.log("comment depth: " + comment.depth)`gives me the following output on my terminal:

```
comment depth: 1
comment depth: 1
comment depth: 1
```

which is expected. Why is it that jade can't read my `depth` member? I have no problems accessing `comment.name`, `comment.body` and `comment._id` in my home.jade file.

Comment: I found a workaround. Instead of doing `comment.depth` I do `comment['depth']` and that seems to give me the value I want. I don't understand why that happens considering `comment.name` and `comment.id` gave me no problems. I'm leaving this question up in the hope that someone can figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

In this callback

`currentComment.save(function (err, currentComment)`

currentComment is a  mongoose **Document** object

It sounds like what you want is the plain result, not the mongoose wrapped result

I'd recommend you call the function `Document#toObject([options])` referenced here http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject before passing the object to your model.

Along a similar vein, you should look into the option `lean` when performing a find operation. When specified, mongoose returns the non-wrapped object.

ex: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findById